# When does a TestFlight external tester status change back to "Notified"?

Tags: ios, testflight

When I saw my TestFlight external testers page in the iTunes Connect website yesterday, it says all the testers have been installed some version of our apps. But when I saw it today, 10 testers status changed back to "Notified". So I wonder why.
My guess is the status changes back to "Notified" when they uninstall our app. But the wired thing is it seems like that suddenly happens for many users at the same time.